# Crystal Reports - 2008 - Numeric field formatting with multiple decimals

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I am working in Crystal Reports 2008 and trying to pull in a data field that contains multiple decimal points.

The source data is formatted as such ###.######.# I have tried to update the Number format but crystal is cutting off the final alphanumeric character that is behind the second decimal point.

I need assistance with writing a formula that will allow formatting to match the structure of my database field.

Comment: Can you show some examples of your field and what you would like it to look like in your report?

Comment: what is double decimal in your value?